# How do I send camel hold back messages to directory when throttling limit is reached?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the situation where I want to accept the first 100 messages in a one hour time frame, and process those via a bean called handleMessage.  Then, any messages over the 100 limit, I would like to simply place them into a directory (or pass to a separate bean) and never send them through the main processing bean. Currently, if 101 messages are received, the 101st message is on hold back and processed by "handleMessage" once the 1 hour time limit is up.

```
<route>
    <from uri="file://inputdir/"/>
    <!-- throttle 100 messages per hour -->
    <throttle timePeriodMillis="3600000">
        <constant>100</constant>
        <bean name="handleMessage" method="process"/>
    </throttle>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

The throttler does not support this, it will always hold back messages and execute them later when the time slot is available.

You would need to write your own custom eip / bean / processor that does what you want.